# Developing a react app using a router with subdomains

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a requirement to split my web app site into several subdomains 
for example :

www.mysite.com: main page
developers.mysite.com : development page
carrers.mysite.com: careers page
blog.mysite.com: blog page

I am using React as my frontend framework and node as my server side.

My question is if it correct to develop an independent react app for each subdomain ? or is there any other alternative I can share my same web app SPA for all of the subdomains?